# ngModel - delete last character

Tags: angular-material2, angular8

i am using `mat-radio-group` to bind my data. here data & value are same. which means i have 4 value binded and all 4 value are same. So to differentiate the radio buttons i added index as last value for every radio button.

Now i want to fetch this radio button value into my typescript and also eliminate the lastcharacter(which is index). so i use ngModel & ngModelChange.

I can get the output. but the `mat-radio-button' is not selecting

Here is my code
`

```
<mat-radio-group class="radioButtonAxis" [(ngModel)]="ngM_Fax" (ngModelChange)="onFaxChange($event)">
              <mat-radio-button *ngFor='let data of resultSet;index as i' [value]='data.Fax+i'>{{data.Fax}}</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
```

```
onFaxChange(value){
    this.ngM_Fax = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
  }
```

`
expecting your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ngModel` wrong. The right value is always in `this.ngM_Fax`, but it has to match 100% [value]. If you want to use the variable without the index, i would suggest to use an extra variable.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fm2gm8) is a working StackBlitz.